# Get sum of margin and height with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, height, sum, margin

I want to get the sum of `margin-top` size and `height` of another layer.

the margin-top of `.nav1` is 30px and the height of `.main` is 28px

I use this code:

```
$('.nav').css('margin-top').replace('px', '') + $('.main').outerHeight()
```

but the result of my sum is `3028`

How can I calculate the sum of these two numbers?

Comment: The object returned by `replace` is a string, you have to convert it to a number,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because you are appending two strings, instead of adding two integers. Try this:

```
var total = parseInt($('.nav').css('margin-top'), 10) + $('.main').outerHeight();
```

Answer (score 53):

You can use `outerHeight(true)` to add margins to height without the maths, if you want to count `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` properties : http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/#outerHeight-includeMargin

```
var heightWithMargin = $('.main').outerHeight(true);
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer.